# How to split an article at the subsubsection level using tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht

`tex4ht` takes a number as an option which specifies the split level, i.e. to make a section or subsection and so on, as separate web pages.

I have an article with sections and subsections and subsubsections. I want each `subsubsection` to be on its own web page since they are large.

I tried split `2` and `3` and `4` and none of these are working. The `subsubsections` all show up on same web page under its parent `subsection` page.

Here is an MWE and the commands I used and a screen shot of the web page

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article} 
    \begin{document}  
    \section{section 1} 
     \subsection{subsection 1} 
        \subsubsection{subsubsection 1} %want this on its webpage
         stuff
        \subsubsection{subsubsection 2} %want this on its webpage
         stuff
        \subsubsection{subsubsection 3} %want this on its webpage
         stuff    
    \end{document}
```

The command

`make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo.tex "mathjax,htm,3"`

produces

```
[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir:
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: dvilualatex
[INFO]    mkparams: Latex options: -jobname=foo
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht.sty: xhtml,mathjax,htm,3,charset=utf-8
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht:  -cmozhtf -utf8
[INFO]    mkparams: build_file: foo.mk4
[INFO]    mkparams: Output format: html5
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo.tex
....
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: executing: t4ht  "foo.dvi"
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2018-07-04-14:25 kpathsea)
t4ht foo.dvi
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
Entering foo.lg
Entering foo.css
Entering foo.tmp

[INFO]    mkutils: Parse LG
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: foo.htm
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: foo.htm
[DEBUG]   tocid: Duplicate id found: subsubsection-. New id: subsubsection-1
[DEBUG]   tocid: Duplicate id found: subsubsection-. New id: subsubsection-2
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: foo.htm
[INFO]    make4ht: outdir:
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: foo.css
[INFO]    make4ht: outdir:
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: foo.tmp
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: tmp file
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: fose1.htm
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: fose1.htm
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: fose1.htm
[INFO]    make4ht: outdir:
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: fosu1.htm
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: fosu1.htm
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: fosu1.htm
[INFO]    make4ht: outdir:
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

The resulting page:

[image]

So all subsubsections are on the same page.

Does `tex4ht` support splitting articles at the subsubsection level?

I am using TL 2021 on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You stopped trying numbers too early. The numbers seem to work like this:

For document classes with `\chapter` command:

- 1 - split at `\part`
- 2 - split at `\chapter`
- 3 - split at `\section`
- 4 - split at `\subsection`
- 5 - split at `\subsubsection`
- 6 - split at `\paragraph`

For document classes without `\chapter` (like `article`):

- 1 - split at `\part`
- 2 - split at `\section`
- 3 - split at `\subsection`
- 5 - split at `\subsubsection`
- 6 - split at `\paragraph`

So you should try

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo.tex "mathjax,htm,5"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That worked,. But I thought because this was article class, then 1-> section and 2->subsection, and so on. I did not know it uses the book numbering that is why I did not think it could be anything over 4.

Comment: @Nasser yes, the code for page breaking is quite complex, and it would be even more if it depended on used class. so the numbers are static. it is true that it isn't documented anywhere, and I had to take a look at the source code to find what the particular numbers do.

Comment: Thanks for the list. But isn't true also that if no split number is given, then it will not split also. So I assume then the "default" internally is to use split=1 if no value is given by user. Yes, it makes sense to use the same numbers for all classes, otherwise it become a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @Nasser yes, I think 1 has some differences to no value at all, it may add some table of contents. but I never used that, it just seems so from reading of the source code. it is old code, it can be more than 15 years old, I haven't changed it at all.

Comment: Hello Michal. I could not verify the update you made. Same levels work in book and article class document. I have an article document with me now, with section and subsections. I wanted each subsection to be on its own web page. I tried `3` but this did _not_ work. The subsections remained on same page as the parent section. Then I tried `4` and now it worked. Each subsection shows on its own page. So this does not agree with what you show above. Try it yourself and see.  I am using TL 2022.

Comment: @Nasser on the example from your question, `3` breaks on `\subsection`, `4` too, and then `5` on `\subsubsection`. So my description is wrong on level 4 and below. It can be a bug, as logically, 4 should break `\subsubsection`. Anyway, `3` should work for your case.

Comment: FYI, I just noticed you wrote above `For document classes without \chapter (like article):`  but then you show `\part`.  as `1`. But an article class does not have `\part`? only book class does.  Or Am I missing something?

Comment: @Nasser Article have `\part` too. But I updated my answer, thanks to `cut-fullname` option it is more obvious what gets broken. It seems that `3` breaks subsections for articles, but only 5 breaks subsubsections.