# Adding hyperref package makes tex4ht change its split level order

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht

I noticed big problem. When I was using split level on document, which should split it at section level because I used level `2`, it did not.

It turned out when I remove the `hyperref`, then it does the right thing and split at section level.

See [How to split an article at the subsubsection level using tex4ht?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631604/how-to-split-an-article-at-the-subsubsection-level-using-tex4ht)  for splitting levels.

[image]

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
 
\begin{document}
\section{section one}
text

\section{section two}
text
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo.tex "mathjax,htm,2"
```

gives this HTML

[image]

You see, it did not split the page.  Now by just removing the `\usepackage{hyperref}` and compiling again, it now gives this correct page, where it puts each section on its own page

[image]

I checked this in TL 2023 and also in TL 2022.

No wonder I always had hard time with split levels with tex4ht. It works different depending if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is used or not. To get it to split at section level when `hyperref` is loaded, level `3` should be used and not `2`. But this is all wrong. Splitting level should not be affected by loading `hyperref`

Bug tracking [link](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?608)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that TeX4ht checks for the existence of the `\@chapter` command to decide which sectioning levels it should use to break to pages. Normally, this command is undefined in the `article` class, but `hyperref` loads the `nameref` package, which seems to define it unconditionally. This means that the `2` option, in that case, breaks pages at `\part` and `\chapter`. We need to undefine `\@chapter` to get things to work correctly, for example using this configuration file:

```
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\chapter\else
\global\let\@chapter\@relax
\fi
\makeatother
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

We need this change to happen before `.4ht` files are processed, which means that it needs to happen before the `\Preamble` command.

The result:

[image]